# Specify specific nock requests

Tags: node.js, nock

I am looking for a way to be able to specify which [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) request will be called for each mocha test.  The issue is that I have ~50 nock request all with the same exact url (post data differs) and it makes using `skip()` and `only()` in mocha a huge pain.  I am thinking of using headers to differentiate. Is there a better option?

Comment: You can call `nock()` for the individual test

Comment: Ah thanks that set me on right track - had all my mocks in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `nock` for the individual test you can reuse URLs for that test.  If it's the same URL you can set it as a variable to save some typing too.

```
var url = "http://example.com";
it("should test something", function () {
    nock(url).post;
});
it("should test another thing", function () {
    nock(url).post;
});
```